# jQuery UI drag div not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm trying to get a div to be `draggable` within the containment of another div.

I'm using jQuery UI to do this but can't seem to get it working.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(".example").draggable({
  containment: ".box"
});
</script>
<div class="box" style="border: solid 1px black; width:500px; height:500px;">
  <div class="example" style="border: solid 1px black; width:90px; height:90px;">Drag me</div>
</div>
```

I'm using bootstrap, is there some other files being loaded that are likely causing this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the `draggable()` function inside a `$(document).ready()`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".example").draggable({ containment: ".box" });
});
```

You can check to see if `draggable()` was applied by right clicking to inspect the element, and see if there is any class such as `ui-draggable` or `ui-draggable-handle` is present. If so, it worked.

Also, make sure you are actually loading the jQuery libraries you need. You can get the latest versions like so:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Just make sure path for JS links are proper "js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" , above solution should work fine. In case path is incorrect you would be getting GET request error in console logs. Prefer using CDN as Andreas' answer suggested, it would be useful during deployment stage of Application.

Answer (score 0):

Your `draggable` function isn't called. Put it in the head section of your markup, like in the [jQuery Ui example](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/). Also you should check your Javascript console for possible errors - there you will see if your jquery is properly loaded or not.

```js
$(".example").draggable({ containment: ".box" });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="box" style="border: solid 1px black; width:500px; height:500px;">
  <div class="example" style="border: solid 1px black; width:90px; height:90px;">Drag me</div>
</div>
```

Comment: console shows that draggable isn't a function "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).draggable is not a function"

Comment: Then your jQuery UI file isnt loaded... check the correct path and spelling. You can use `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>` instead of your local file and see if it works.

Comment: Just tried using the online hosted js files in your snippet and commenting out mine but still having the same problem

Comment: Look into your browsers source code: is the jquery-ui.min.js link actually leading to the content of the file?

Comment: Both link correctly to the file in the source code, links are https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js They are in the correct order with jquery ui second

Comment: Do you have your code online for us to check? If you get the "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).draggable is not a function" error, its for sure that your jQuery UI lib is not loaded properly...

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Containment drag functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( ".example" ).draggable({ containment: ".box" });
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="box" style="border: solid 1px black; width:500px; height:500px;">
<div class="example" style="border: solid 1px black; width:90px; height:90px;">Drag me</div>
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This code works standalone but when I implement into my webpage i'm still getting the problem. I'm using bootstrap, is there some other files being loaded that are likely causing this?

Comment: make sure you are actually loading the jQuery libraries you need.

load following libraries into your webpage by inserting them in `<head>` section.


`<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">`

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">`

`<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>`

`<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>`